# SSIS Load Excel file with dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, load

I'm new to SSIS and have been looking for a solution to this challenge for a week without success.

Actually I receive an Excel file that has around 200 columns, but, to keep it simple, let's imagine that  I have 10 columns, the first 3 columns are Product Name,  Product Category and Client Name, then all other columns are the Months with the sales forecast, with it, I have something like:

```
Product ! Category ! Client ! Jan-18 | Feb18 | Mar18 !
Prd A   | Cat A    | ClientA| 10     | 20    | 25    | 
Prd B   | Cat B    | ClientB| 70     | 30    | 100   |
```

My problem is that every month I'll get a new month in this file , and I cant' import only the last month, as the historical data can change along the time .

So, next month I can have , for instance:

```
Product ! Category ! Client ! Jan-18 | Feb18 | Mar18 ! Apr18|
Prd A   | Cat A    | ClientA| 50     | 40    | 250   | 40   |
Prd B   | Cat B    | ClientB| 50     | 40    | 150   | 80   |
```

How can I import this into SQL? I was thinking of doing it using Script Task but was not able to write the script as I don't know C# or VB.

Is there a way to perform this load without Script Task? If so how? If just possible with ST, can you help me writing this?

Comment: Take a look at Masud's blog here - it gave me the leg up I needed with something very similar: https://masudprogrammer.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/ssis-c-load-an-csv-file-handle-any-change-in-the-number-or-name-of-the-columns/

Comment: You could just create all the columns you want first, and they would be NULL, no?

Comment: SSIS is very finicky about the number of columns in the data flow tasks - if you change it between the runs, the SSIs will fail the task, I've tried to emulate this problem using Excel DAta source with command `Select * from [Sheet1$A2:ZZ1000]` but only not null columns are being read and you can't force creating null column AFAIK. You have to use the script then...

Comment: Matt, thanks a lot, your suggestion works perfectly, I just can't find where I mark your answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Lucas, one workaround that I use when I face this same problem is, import the table to a staging table with only one varchar(max) column. Don't forget to include a delimiter. This way, SSIS will accept the file with as many column as it has. Once this data is inside your database, you can create a procedure to break this data into multiple columns and send to the definitive table. I know there are other ways but this process has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Jader, but was this with excel file ?

Comment: Yes, it was. I had to import several stock market excel files and the columns were not fixed, so I did was:

**CREATE TABLE  XLImport3  (COL1 VARCHAR(MAX))**

**SELECT * INTO XLImport3 FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
   'Data Source=C:\test\xltest.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Customers$]**

**SELECT COL1 FROM XLImport3**

Once the file is inside your table, you can break them based on the separators (usually ';') using string functions in SQL and insert them into your definitive table. This can be automatized. Try this solution and tell me if it works for you.